# Best way to call Webservice via Get

Tags: c#, http-get

I am calling a 3rd party API that I access with an HTTP Get. I have a working example to call this API using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse and it works fine. I wanted to make sure this is best practice, or should I be using something else. This is not a Web solution so it does not have MVC/Web Api references built in. Here is some sample code

```
     protected WebResponse executeGet(string endpoint, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, bool skipEncode = false)
    {
        string urlPath = this.baseURL + endpoint + "?" +
                         createEncodedString(parameters, skipEncode);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending to: " + urlPath);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlPath);
        req.Method = "GET";
        return req.GetResponse();
    }
```

Is this the preferred way to call Get Apis?

Comment: This isn't on-topic for SO. This might be a good candidate for code-review although you'll probably need to supply more information about your .net framework and any other systemic information before others can help.

Comment: For reference, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I know SO discourages "best-practice" questions, the "Microsoft recommended" way I've seen WebAPIs called is using `HttpClient` in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package. Besides Windows and web projects, this package is supported for Windows Phone and Windows Store projects too.

Here's what their sample GET code looks like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
    }
}
```

FMI, see [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)